# Study the monotonicity of the following function? No derivatives/graphing

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

The function is the following:
$f(x) = x^{21} + 3x + 1$
I have to study the monotonicity without graphing (as I don't know how to graph higher than mx+b at the moment) and without derivatives (as I haven't learnt them). Intuitively it is strictly increasing, according to Desmos graphing it is strictly increasing (so I was correct I guess).

My approach would be with the "rate of monotonicity" as we call it here:
We take two variables $x_1 \ne x_2$. We proceed by doing $R(x_1,x_2) = (f(x_1) - f(x_2)/(x_1-x_2)$
If my calculations are correct, $R(x_1,x_2) = (x_1^{21}-x_2^{21})/(x_1-x_2) + 3$

I just have to prove this $R(x_1, x_2)$ is strictly greater than $0$. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will write $x$ and $y$ instead of $x_1$ and $x_2$, just to make typing easier.  We may assume that $x>y$.  Then $$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=\frac{x^{21}-y^{21}}{x-y}+3=3+x^{20}+x^{19}y+x^{18}y^2+\cdots+xy^{19}+y^{20}$$

Now, this is clearly $>0$ if $x$ and $y$ are both $\geq0$ or both $\leq0$, so (since $x>y$,) we have only the case $y<0<x$ left to deal with.  Rather than trying to deal with the above expression, we go back to the original definition of $f$ and see that when $y<0$ we have $f(y)<1$ and when $x>0$ we have $f(x)>1.$